# How can I run code written in QT2?

Tags: qt

I have some code that when debugging it in qt5, I see many syntactic and library errors. I find that this could have been written in qt2. how can I run this code?
I try to install qt2 from archive of Qt.io but that's unsuccessful too.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to run this code without installing Qt 2 on a *supported* platform. This means old Visual Studio for Windows, on an old Windows version (XP), or an old linux virtual machine. The README for Qt 2 should describe what platforms and compilers were supported.

For porting, there are two ways to approach such code:

1. Do a direct port to Qt 5. Simply go through all errors, and port to the new APIs as needed.
2. Do a step-by-step port. Install Qt 3, port to Qt 3, then install Qt 4, port to Qt 4, finally port to Qt 5. There are tools in each Qt version to take some drudgery out of porting from the preceding major version.

Comment: thanks, so i think second way is better?why you don't suggest  a third way that install QT2?is it possible at all?

Comment: when I install qt4 I have should remove qt3 an its component too?

Comment: @mah.hb Qt installations can coexist, you simply put them into separate folders. I think I have about 10 different versions here, for example.